# How to set image as a background from database in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

i'm a beginner in ruby on rails. so far I can only make a "create, show, delete, update data, and file upload using carrierwave" and I have problem when I want to set a image as background from database.

i use carrierwave for image uploader and the image save in **public/uploads/user/picture/** and this part of **show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Image:</strong><br>
  <%= image_tag @user.picture.thumb.url %>
</p>
```

then I have **home.html.erb**

```
<div class="img-fill" style="background-image: url('..');"></div>
```

1. how to make an image into the background on the page **home.html.erb** of image I choose?
2. What code should I add on show.html.erb to instruct the image used as background in home.html.erb?
   thx

Comment: Is there any login process you have included before visit the home/show page?

Comment: no login process, i just make standard CRUD like generate scaffold and i only add carrierwave+mini_magick then i add a new page in views/users/ called home.html.erb

Comment: just add in the controller (users#home) action `@user = User.first` for example or which user's background you want to display

Comment: wow it works :D, but when I upload a new image and while in show.html.erb then I click 'Home' the background doesn't change. on my form, I have a name and picture. how to write for the action on the controller when i want to take only the picture ? i try `@user = User.find(:avatar)` but not work

Comment: from which user you want to display the background-image?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `<%= @user.picture.url %>` it will output the url of the image. So now you can place it into the `style` attribute like that:

```
<div class="img-fill" style="background-image: url('<%= @user.picture.url %>');"></div>
```

Comment: it not work, i add <%= link_to 'Home', home_path %> on show.html.erb, and i add <%= @user.picture.url %> in background-image url then when i show the image then i click Home, i got error "undefined method `picture' for nil:NilClass" did i miss something?

Comment: you have to declare `@user` in your controller #home action.